# Enable 'unhide' the 'New' button (System button) on Lead entity

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2016

I want to Enable 'unhide' the 'New' button (System button) on Lead entity which was hidden due to some scenario. 
I have tried some approaches to achieve this :

a) I have tried using 'Ribbon Workbench' to unhide but couldn't able to find the button itself.

b) Also Tried editing the Customizations.xml (for the solution with Lead entity and Application ribbon components) to remove the command  and reimported.

c) Used 'VisualRibbonEditor' but same case as Ribbon Workbench.

d) Also i am able to repro the issue "Hide/Unhide 'New' button on Lead" on trial instance as well.

**CRM Version Using:**
Dynamics CRM 365 Version 1710 (9.1.0.1677) Online

Can you please help me fix this issue. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Do you have permission to create Lead records?

Comment: Yes , having the Lead Entity Permission.

Comment: If you don't have the Create Lead Privilege, even if you manage to show the "New" button, yo would not be able to create the record

Comment: I know there is a major bug currently with the ribbon in CRM online.  It might be related, not sure though.

Comment: Is this happening for only Lead entity? Can you share some screenshot?

Comment: Currently for Lead Entity only ,screenshot as simply "New"button existing on the screen and i am trying to Unhide it which is System button , so s it possible?

Comment: to be clear - you are trying to do just like explained [here](https://ribbonworkbench.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/102796-5-hiding-unhiding-ribbon-elements) but you are not seeing the option to unhide or its disabled - correct?

Comment: Yes its right, but i am trying to Enable Unhide the System button only not custom button.

Comment: you can try to export lead entity from working instance without any forms or fields or anything just the entity, on infected solution do the same in clean solution export only the entity without any fields or forms or anything, copy the ribbon xml from sol 1 (the working one) to sol 2 (the one from infected instance) zip it , upload it again publish  and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I tried working on your particular issue.

Screenshot 1 shows Leads with New Button Hidden. There is no New Button
[image]

Screenshot 2 Shows Ribbon Workbench where Hide rule for New button is removed (unhide)
[image]
Screenshot 3 shows CRM Lead Entity with New button after Hide rule is removed.
[image]